# JQuery Ajax returns an error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web

I am using this code :

```
function fetchGame(xval,oval) {
            $.get("games.php", { x: xval, o: oval }, function(xml,status) {
                $("#game").empty();
                var row;
                $(xml).find("value").each(function(index, value) {
                    if ( index % 3 == 0) {
                        row = $("<tr></tr>");
                        $("#game").append(row);
                    }
                    console.log($("<td width=\"50\" height=\"50\"></td>").text(value));
                    row.append($("<td width=\"50\" height=\"50\"></td>").text(value));
                });

            },"xml");
        }
```

And I'm catching the Ajax errors with this:

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error + "\nText : "+ xhr.ResponseText+"\nXML : "+xhr.ResponseXML);

  }
});
```

You can see it work here in the site I'm building for a web course :

```
http://62.219.127.85/sites/2013b/xox/xo.php?x=7&o=8
```

and see that the return xml is valid and correct :

```
http://62.219.127.85/sites/2013b/xox/games.php?x=7&o=8
```

To those who dont want to get in the site, it returns :

```
<game>
    <x>
        <id>7</id>
        <id>Ofek Ron</id>
    </x>
    <o>
        <id>8</id>
        <id>Avi Fahima</id>
    </o>
    <value>o</value>
    <value>x</value>
    <value>-</value>
    <value>x</value>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>x</value>
    <value>x</value>
    <value>o</value>
    <value>o</value>
</game>
```

Yet, I get this weird error on the get request, which is very uninformative "error" is all the info they could give me:
[image: Error]

Comment: `$.get("games.php", {x: x, o: o}, function(xml,status) ...` reads better...

Comment: An example of the xml being returned being included in your question would be far more useful than a link to your site.

Comment: im new to this as you can see... please focus on the problem..

Comment: @KevinB Ok, i have included it, do you want all the source code as well?

Comment: no, that would probably be irrelevant

Comment: First, tell jQuery that you are requesting xml. `$.get(url,data,successhandler,"xml")`

Comment: ok i have included the alert itself

Comment: @KevinB tried it, still no luck...

Comment: Next, inspect the response text: `console.log(xhr.responseText)` (in the error handler)

Comment: @KevinB undefined....

Comment: That tells me the server isn't actually responding with xml. Open your console and go to the network tab, are any of the requests red?

Comment: but it is if i go there manually

Comment: Right, but it's not returning anything when you request it with ajax. we need to figure out why.

Comment: Hardcode `{ x: xval, o: oval }` to be `{ x: 7, o: 8 }` to rule out your params being wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36050/discussion-between-ofek-ron-and-kevin-b)